# match_query is not working in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new ElasticSearch.Recently we started using ElasticSearch in my project.
I am trying to get data based on first_name and last_name by using match_query.
I write query like this

```
{
"query":{
  "multi_match" : {
    "query": "michkel",
    "fields": [ "last_name"] 

  }
}
}
```

My index name is employee and it contains below documents

```
{
   "first_name":"smith",
"last_name":"michkel",
"age":25,
"doj":"2015-05-2"
},
{
   "first_name":"john",
"last_name":"smith",
"age":46,
"doj":"1989-03-25"
}
```

when run the above query i am getting total records but my requirement is if i give  "query": "michkel" like this, then only one record is match with my documents.
Give me solutions as soon as possible 
And one more question 
I want to search based on user given date.My user will give date like this 1989-04-15.for this i write like below
    {
    "query":{
      " query_string" : {
        "query": "1989-04-15",

```
  }
}
}
{"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query_fetch], all shards failed; shardFailures {[du1Tb7U8QLWSnXO2m9ATCg][employee][0]: SearchParseException[[employee][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\n\"query\":{\n  \" query_string\" : {\n    \"query\": \"1989-04-15\",\n\n  }\n}\n}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[employee] No query registered for [ query_string]]; }]","status":400}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `multi_match` use [bool](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-filter.html) filter as below :

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "last_name": "michkel"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As per your edited question you should use same above in match replace as `"doj": "1989-04-15"` and if you want to find out combing both `last_name` and `doj` then use query as below :

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        {
                            "query_string": {
                                "query": "1989-04-15"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "last_name": "michkel"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just now i updated my questions, once see and give me solution